# Canonical URL Rewrite for multiple domain extensions in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sitefinity-4

I'd like to achieve the following:

I have a website that hosts multiple languages. For each language there is a unique domain.

```
domain.eu --> English
domain.nl --> Dutch
domain.at --> German
```

I want to write an URL Rewrite action that redirects as follows:

```
www.domain.eu --> domain.eu
www.domain.nl --> domain.nl
www.domain.at --> domain.at
```

Can I do this in one rewrite rule inside IIS?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Just do a 301 redirect (usually you can do this in the cPanel).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the standard URL rewrite tool inside IIS or extend the standard URL rewrite tool with this extension: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

We used it to redirect requests of non-www domains to www-domains and I am sure your case can be solved using this tool as well.